# How can I play Pokémon GO without Internet?

Tags: pokemon-go

I downloaded Pokémon GO on my Samsung Galaxy Express and I can play it at home, but when I go outside I can't play because there is no Internet.

How can I play Pokémon GO without Internet outside?

Answer (score 27):

Quite simply, you can't. The game requires an internet connection.

Comment: how do I get internet outside

Comment: That's something you have to discuss with your cell phone provider. @LEE

Comment: @LEE If your tablet does not have 3G/4G capability, you're going to have to get a smartphone or a tablet that does.

Answer (score 17):

<sub>This is an attempt to build on the obvious "you can't" answer.</sub>

Many cities around the world are funding infrastructure projects to connect their cities with free, public WiFi access points.  The [LinkNYC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkNYC) project is a perfect example of this, as their goal is to work with the New York City government to add WiFi kiosks to every street corner.

I have successfully played Pokemon Go on a device without cellular connection by walking between LinkNYC hotspots in Manhattan.