# Can I play pokemon go without wifi

Tags: pokemon-go

I have no data plan.  I need help,  really want to play please and thank you

Comment: Question is a duplicate but I don't believe the answer there is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways for a person to play pokemon go outside without a data plan that work surprisingly well:

- Use provided wifi, a lot of cafes and malls offer free wifi and universities/colleges offer a pretty wide cover of wifi across campus
- Have a friend provide a hotspot for you to connect to which will let you to play with your friends but you just can't stray too far from him/her

Source: I've used both of these methods before and have caught plenty of pokemon

Comment: This is a good answer that might get more exposure if you move it to the [duplicate target](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275767/how-can-i-play-pok%c3%a9mon-go-without-internet).

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot play it without wi-fi sadly, however you can play it while at your house(if you have wifi) or a local place with wi-fi and hope for random Pokemon to appear across the street, or use a lure module or ensense to get Pokemon to appear where you are. Some towns offer free wi-fi and although the speeds might not be great it could still work...