# How do I play Pokemon Go without a celluar connection or Wifi?

Tags: pokemon-go

I would like to play Pokemon Go, but my phone does not have mobile data. My friends appear to be able to play Pokemon Go without SIM card or personal hotspot. When I asked them, they have claimed they're using a beta version that does not need Wifi.

I have read [How can I play Pokémon GO without Internet?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275767/how-can-i-play-pok%C3%A9mon-go-without-internet) but it does not help.

Can I play Pokemon GO without a mobile data connection or wifi internet?

Comment: Pokemon GO *requires* an internet connection. If you don't have a means of connecting to the internet, you can't play. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @MageXy well my friends dont even have a SIM card or personal Homespot

Comment: They are connecting to the internet somehow, otherwise they would not be able to play either. All I can tell you is that Pokemon GO requires internet. If your friends claim they can play without it, I suggest asking them for details. I suspect they are connecting to a nearby network without realizing it. In any case, it sounds like they would be more help to you than we will be, since we've already linked the answer to your question.

Answer (score -2):

One most definitely can play Pokemon Go without a mobile data plan. With my android I do not turn data on. You can also play when you are not connected to a hotspot, but there must be some kind of internet/wifi connection. I rarely turn on data in order to save $$ when I play this game.